# React router path and nested path not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm having a problem with this path in react router v4.

```
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/users' component={ListRoute} />
    <Route exact path='/users/:id' component={ShowRoute} />
    <Route path='/users/:id/edit' component={EditRoute} />

    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
```

If I try to get to /users/4 or /users/4/edit I get not found. Perhaps have to do with exact or I'm doing the path incorrectly

Comment: Your code works for me, are you sure there is not any problem somewhere else?

Comment: Here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/1v1r08qp33

Comment: Yes I already found the solution, as you said the code was fine. Problem was it this switch as behind another switch and that one had an exact property. I removed that and everything started working. I guess we can delete this question

Comment: The decision is yours.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this instead:

```
<Route path='/users/editUser/:id' component={EditRoute} />
```

this will work for ever!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you would be rendering both `/users/:id` and `/users/:id/edit`, What i would do is replace the first with `/users/user/:id` and the ladder with `users/edit/:id`, this way, you will only render one component at a time and avoid several errors.